# How can Star-Lord fly horizontally with only boots rockets?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, we see this scene in the final battle

> [image: Finale Battle]

Star-Lord is flying horizontally without any rocket to stabilize him as we can see for Iron Man and Iron Patriot in the same picture.

How is it possible? Has Peter Quill got an anti-gravity suit to help him or anything else?

Comment: None of them have anything stablising them, Iron Man and Iron Patriots hand boosters are pointed behind them. Best guess, they are flying "fast enough" it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find [a video of skydivers performing the "delta" maneuver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLoNtIgovGI).

This is a body lift glide, like flying a wing suit without the wing membranes.  Push a human body forward at around 100+ mph, and the airflow over the torso and legs (in Earth's atmosphere) can generate enough lift to support the body.  Obviously, when skydiving, this doesn't equal level flight; considerable downward velocity is still required to keep the speed high, but in delta, a skydiver can travel horizontally at around a third of their vertical fall speed.

Now, give the skydiver rocket boots (and this has been done, with micro turbojets and wing suit, though not as far as I know for a no-membrane delta) and the vertical fall can be eliminated.  Minimum flight speed would be close to 120 mph, but since Quill's boot jets can lift his weight against at least 1G and don't appear to require large fuel tanks, I see no reason he couldn't maintain this speed as long as necessary.

Comment: Are you saying I could be Star-Lord. Because it sounds like you're saying I could be Star-Lord.

Comment: Officer Dey: @PaulD.Waite hey look, if it isn’t our  ***Star-prince***? 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, aside from his Celestial ancestry (which lets him handle an Infinity Stone without dying), Peter Quill is a normal human -- all his "hero" stuff is done with technology.  That we don't know how to make yet.

Comment: @ZeissIkon gotcha, that is fair. If you could figure out how to make it before my birthday I would happily be your first customer.